# JSF Bookmarkable URL to update ui:decorate value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, myfaces

Need help here. I'm trying to make my current project bookmarkable. My current design can basically be summed up in this code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="contentUrl" value="#{navigationBean.contentUrl}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="/views/template/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="leftpane">
                <ui:include src="/views/admin/menu_administrator.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="rightpane">
                <p:growl showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
                <ui:decorate template="/views/admin/content/#{navigationBean.contentUrl}.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

So I have this template to make the site 30/70 look having the "leftpane" contain the menu and the "rightpane" to display the output content. What I want is to be able to change the output in the "rightpane" depending on the URL sent:

```
www.mysite.com/projectitle/views/admin/Administrator.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;contentUrl=cont_admin_rapptmnttype
```

Whatever will be constructed in this url: /views/admin/content/#{navigationBean.contentUrl}.xhtml on the "rightpane" also has a corresponding backing bean to generate the needed output

I'm using Primefaces3.5, MyFaces2.0, WAS8.5

Hope someone could help me out on this. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I am using a p:menuitem to set the contentUrl like

```
<p:menuitem value="Appointment Type" id="cont_admin_rapptmnttype"
                                ajax="false" outcome="#{navigationBean.currentMode}" >
                                <f:param name="contentUrl" value="cont_admin_rapptmnttype"/>
</p:menuitem>
```

But when I click on the menuitem I get a Stackoverflow exception which, as it turns, is caused by:

```
<ui:decorate template="/views/admin/content/#{navigationBean.contentUrl}.xhtml"/>
```

Which is the one I'm trying to update.

Here is the recurring exception in the stacktrace:

```
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.DecorateHandler.apply(DecorateHandler.java:137)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:324)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:54)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:324)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:54)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:150)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:322)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:369)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:347)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:215)
```